# reportlab.pdfgen generating corrupted PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf-generation, reportlab

I have a Django Python 3.6.5 view that's intended to write and export a report to PDF using reportlab.pdfgen. I can get the PDF file to generate when the view is called, but the .pdf file that's generated is corrupted. I'm following reportlab's documentation as best as I can tell, is there an issue with how I'm creating and writing the PDF?

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import FileResponse
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

from app.models import Organization
from app.models import Question, Report

# add a footer to the PDF
def add_pdf_footer(pdf):
    date_str = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    pdf.saveState()
    width, height = letter
    pdf.setFont("Helvetica", 9)
    text = f"Exported on {date_str}"
    pdf.drawRightString(width - 50, 700, text)
    pdf.restoreState()

def export_report_pdf(request, report_id):
    org = Organization.objects.get(id=request.session["org"])

    try:
        report = Report.objects.get(id=report_id, org=org)

        # build file
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')

        filename = f"{org.name}_{report.report_type.standard}_report_{report.year}_export_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')}.pdf"
        
        response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename={filename}"
        buffer = BytesIO()
        sections = report.get_sections()
        headers = ["standard", "topic", "code", "question", "value", "units", "note"]
        if len(sections) > 1:
            headers = ["standard", "topic", "section", "code", "question", "value", "units", "note"]
        answers = report.get_or_create_answers(request.user)
        answers_to_export = []
        for answer in answers:
            question = answer.question
            if question.dependency is not None:
                dependency = question.dependency
                dep_answer = list(filter(lambda x: x.question == dependency, answers))[0]
                if question.is_dependency_resolved(dep_answer):
                    answers_to_export.append(answer)
            else:
                answers_to_export.append(answer)
        
        pdf = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=letter)
        pdf.setFont("Helvetica", 15)
        pdf.drawString(100,800, "{org.name} - {report.year} {report.report_type.standard} - {report.report_type.name} Report")
        pdf.setFont("Helvetica", 12)
        y = 750
        
        for header in headers:
            pdf.drawString(100, y, header)
            y -= 25
        
        for answer in answers_to_export:
            qtype = answer.question.question_type
            if qtype == Question.QUESTION_TYPE_MULTISELECT:
                value = ", ".join([ans.value for ans in answer.values_selected.all()])
            elif qtype == Question.QUESTION_TYPE_SELECT:
                value = answer.value_selected.value if answer.value_selected else ""
            elif qtype == Question.QUESTION_TYPE_DATE:
                value = answer.value_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            else:
                value = answer.value
            if len(sections) > 1:
                pdf.drawString(180, y, answer.question.section)
                pdf.drawString(260, y, answer.question.code)
                if answer.question.text:
                    pdf.drawString(340, y, answer.question.text)
                if value:
                    pdf.drawString(420, y, value)
                if answer.question.units:
                    pdf.drawString(500, y, answer.question.units)
                if answer.note:
                    pdf.drawString(580, y, answer.note)
                y -= 30
            else:
                pdf.drawString(260, y, answer.question.code)
                if answer.question.text:
                    pdf.drawString(340, y, answer.question.text)
                if value:
                    pdf.drawString(420, y, value)
                if answer.question.units:
                    pdf.drawString(500, y, answer.question.units)
                if answer.note:
                    pdf.drawString(580, y, answer.note)
                y -= 30
        
        # set PDF export footer
        add_pdf_footer(pdf)
        pdf.save()

        # return file

        return response

    except:
        
        log.error(traceback.print_exc())

        return redirect("admin-report")
```